# como colocar subtitulos en un jtable

Tags: java, jtable

Necesito colocar subtitulo en un jtable, es decir que una celda ocupe todo el ancho de la tabla, alguien me ayuda. desde ya muchas gracias

Comment: Poca info :( Si no pones código que hayas intentado ni nada no va a ser posible ayuda :S

Answer (score 0):

Eso es bastante complicado. Necesitas crear TableCellRender que controle el renderizado de las celdas. Aunque el componente jTable no fue creado para este tipo de situaciones